# How can i access ip(7) man page (Ubuntu)

Tags: manpage

I try to see the man page of the `IP(7)`, but if I type in "`man ip`" then i get the IP(8) man page. My goal is to see the `"struct sockaddr_in"` struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can additionally specify the section in the call to the `man` command:

```
man 7 ip
```

You could consult man's man page for that: `man man` :-) There you will find this variant:

```
man -K [-w|-W] [-S list] [-i|-I] [--regex] [section] term ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `man 7 ip` at the prompt. As said in the `man`'s manual

> A section no,  if  provided, will direct man to look only in that section of
>          the manual.

Demo

```
$ man 7 ip
IP(7)                      Linux Programmer's Manual                     IP(7)

NAME
       ip - Linux IPv4 protocol implementation

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/socket.h>

.
.
.
.
```

And `struct sockaddr_in` here for you!

```
       struct sockaddr_in {
           sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
           in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
           struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
       };
```